# creating new json file when button is clicked

Tags: python, json, tkinter, tkinter-entry

When opening my application, it loads a config.json file.

```
def load_profiledata(self):
    self.log_print("Loading profiles...")
    self.config = {}
    try:
        with open('./config.json', 'r+') as f:
            self.config = json.load(f)

        self.container.value_prof.set(self.config['prof'])
        self.container.value_name.set(self.config['name'])
        self.container.value_email.set(self.config['email'])
        self.container.value_phone.set(self.config['phone'])
        self.container.value_addr1.set(self.config['addr1'])
        self.container.value_addr2.set(self.config['addr2'])
        self.container.value_zip.set(self.config['zip'])
        self.container.value_cardnumber.set(self.config['cardnumber'])
        self.container.value_cardexpmonth.set(self.config['cardexpmonth'])
        self.container.value_cardexpyear.set(self.config['cardexpyear'])
        self.container.value_cardcode.set(self.config['cardcode'])
        self.log_print("loaded config.json")
    except Exception:
        self.log_print("failed to load profile")
        self.save_profile()
```

I need `save_profile` button within my gui to generate a new json file with the same fields.

```
def save_profile(self):
    self.config['prof'] = self.container.value_prof.get()
    self.config['name'] = self.container.value_name.get()
    self.config['email'] = self.container.value_email.get()
    self.config['phone'] = self.container.value_phone.get()
    self.config['addr1'] = self.container.value_addr1.get()
    self.config['addr2'] = self.container.value_addr2.get()
    self.config['zip'] = self.container.value_zip.get()
    self.config['cardnumber'] = self.container.value_cardnumber.get()
    self.config['cardexpmonth'] = self.container.value_cardexpmonth.get()
    self.config['cardexpyear'] = self.container.value_cardexpyear.get()
    self.config['cardcode'] = self.container.value_cardcode.get()
    with open('./config.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(self.config, f)

    self.log_print("profile saved")
    self.profiles_print(self.container.value_prof.get())
```

How would i be able to generate a new json file with the name of the file being the value of `self.container.value_prof.get()`? is any of this possible...in python

help is appreciated.
thanks!

Comment: `fname = self.container.value_prof.get()` and `with open(f"{fname}.json") as f`

Comment: thanks! so i added ```fname = self.container.value_prof.get()``` and changed ```with open('./config.json', 'w') as f:``` to ```with open(f"{fname}.json") as f:``` and now getting "no such file or directory" error.

Comment: You still need to use `, 'w'` and open the file for writing.

Comment: !! tysm, both of you

Answer (score 0):

`fname = self.container.value_prof.get()` to make the file name the value i wanted

`with open(f"{fname}.json", 'w') as f:` to change the name

thanks to @frost-nzcr4 and @Karl Knechtel